# glassfish-resource.xml vs persistence.xml

Tags: xml, glassfish, persistence

I've created a rest service project and I'm struggling to understand why both are present. If I have all the JDBC information in the glassfish-resource.xml, what is the function of the persistence.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both have complete different responsibilities.

The `glassfish-resources.xml` is provided to the server to register the JDBC connection pool and the JDBC resourece, e.g., on the server level.

The `persistence.xml`is used to register a persistence unit to the application on application level. You are able to use one of the registered JDBC Resources, which are provided by your `glassfish-resources.xml` as well as JDBC Resources that are predefined directly on the server, or even a complete different connection that you are specifying directly in the `persistence.xml`

If you are only using the database connection for the Persistence Unit, then it is totally fine to define it directly `persistence.xml`. But registering a JDBC Resource through the `glassfish-resources.xml` (or directly on the server) has the advantage, that you are able to use those JDBC Resource not even for your Persistence Unit, but also for some JDBC Realm(s) or whatever you may use with JDBC...